# Alternate ways to log into BeagleBone Black when static IP is unknown

Tags: linux, debian, beagleboneblack

I am attempting to access my BeagleBone Black but I am having some issues and I'm needing some help.

I messed around with my BBB almost 2 years back and I statically set the IP address for eth0. Unfortunately, I don't recall what I changed it to. If I knew the network, I could probably figure it out but I haven't the slightest clue what it could be.

I am running Windows 10 on my laptop and I have a USB to USB-mini running to the device which provides to it power and a connection.

I have installed the latest drivers, PuTTY, and WireShark. I made sure the drivers were imported, ran WireShark for DHCP requests/ARP broadcasts, LL DNS updates, or SSH port references but I wasn't seeing anything on that particular interface on my laptop (ran as promiscuous and nonpromiscuous).

I read that the default IP address for the `beaglebone.local` is 192.168.7.2 but I wasn't able to reach it via ICMP, HTTP, or SSL.

I assumed the USB connection provides either an Ethernet-over-USB connection or a serial connection (UART through USB), so, I have both the USB connected and the Ethernet cable connected.

To see if I could just use a serial connection with PuTTY (Serial-to-USB), I opened Device Manager to see which COM port it was using. The odd thing is that COM ports aren't listed in Dev Manager, not even by default when nothing is connected. There also wasn't section for Unknown Devices.

I figured at this point, it wouldn't hurt to download the latest release of Debian for BeagleBone. I wrote the .img to a 32GB MicroSD card and held down the USER/BOOT button while I applied power (as per the instructions).

Still no luck and I'm now out of ideas.

I only have a laptop at my disposal, currently. I don't have immediate access to a monitor, mouse, and keyboard so I wouldn't be able to view what is happening internally. The LED0 is giving me the standard heartbeat flash (2 consecutive flashes followed by a longer off period).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

TIA

Comment: One more way in is the serial console on J1, I've often used that in the past.

Comment: @Robert is that the JTAG connection? If so, would I use PuTTY? What would the connection setting be?

Comment: Yes, it's a connector with 6 pins. As far as I remember it's the "serial" setting with speed set to 115200bits/s in Putty.

Comment: @Robert I don't have a TTL (FTDI) cable. I should probably get one. The USB connection should provide the same connection as well as ethernet-over-USB. I figured out what the issue was, though. The cable that I had was cheap and only provided +5VDC power but not the UART (RX\TX) connection through USB. Grabbed a known-good cable and it works perfectly. Though I'm not sure why I couldn't access it through the Cat5 ethernet connection. Services were up and I was on the correct subnet. Mox nix. Thanks for the assistance, though.

Comment: Are you running linux or windows on your laptop ? If windows then you can probably try [this](http://beaglebone.cameon.net/home/internet-over-usb). If you are running linux then you can take a look at the `/etc/network/interfaces` file on the Micro SD Card to see how the network is configured.